# Handle all types of Retrofit errors properly with rxjava

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-binding

I'm new to `Rxjava` with `Retrofit` and I'm asking for the best right way to handle all possible status in Retrofit using `rxjava` and `rxbinding` which includes:

1. No Internet connection.
2. Null response from server.
3. Success response.
4. Error response and show the error message like `Username or password is incorrect`.
5. Other errors like `connection reset by peers`.

Comment: have a look at https://bytes.babbel.com/en/articles/2016-03-16-retrofit2-rxjava-error-handling.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having exception subclass for each important failure response.
Exceptions are delivered as `Observable.error()`, while values are delivered through stream without any wrapping.

1) No internet - ConnectionException

2) Null - just NullPointerException

4) Check for "Bad Request" and throw IncorrectLoginPasswordException

5) any other error is just NetworkException

You can map errors with `onErrorResumeNext()` and `map()`

For example

Typical retrofit method that fetches data from web service:

```
public Observable<List<Bill>> getBills() {
    return mainWebService.getBills()
            .doOnNext(this::assertIsResponseSuccessful)
            .onErrorResumeNext(transformIOExceptionIntoConnectionException());
}
```

Method that assures response is ok, throws appropriate exceptions otherwise

```
private void assertIsResponseSuccessful(Response response) {
    if (!response.isSuccessful() || response.body() == null) {
        int code = response.code();
        switch (code) {
            case 403:
                throw new ForbiddenException();
            case 500:
            case 502:
                throw new InternalServerError();
            default:
                throw new NetworkException(response.message(), response.code());
        }

    }
}
```

IOException means there is no network connection so I throw ConnectionException

```
private <T> Function<Throwable, Observable<T>> transformIOExceptionIntoConnectionException() {
    // if error is IOException then transform it into ConnectionException
    return t -> t instanceof IOException ? Observable.error(new ConnectionException(t.getMessage())) : Observable.error(
            t);
}
```

For your login request create new method that will check if login/password are ok.

And at the end there is

```
subscribe(okResponse -> {}, error -> {
// handle error
});
```